# jQuery $.getJSON not sending request in IE (works in FF and Chrome)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, getjson

I am in IE9's debug mode. I put a breakpoint on the first line (below), and it hits. However, my breakpoint on the first line in the callback is never hit.

After looking in the **Network** tab, I don't see a request to the URL (set to `"http://localhost/PopNote/"`).

```
$.getJSON(
            URL + "messages/getUnreadMessages.json?" + Math.random(), // add random to prevent IE cache
            {
                productKey      : this.productKey,
                listIds         : this.listIds,
                personEmail     : this.personEmail
            },
            function(data) {    
                if(data.messages.length == 0) return;
```

Why is the request not being sent (and only in IE)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried attaching a failure handler to see if you are getting any kind of response?

Comment: Are you closing out the brackets and parenthesis correctly? Are all those variables always initiated? I once had a case similar to this where I thought it was a compatability issue, and it turned out to be a syntax code error where firefox processed the request anyway and IE didn't.

Comment: @SteveGreatrex: How can I attach a failure handler? I don't see anything like that in the jQuery docs.

Comment: @AFinkelstein: Yes and yes. I get 0 errors in IE.

Comment: To attach a failure handler, use the $.ajax method instead. $.getJson is just calling $.ajax if you look at the docs.

Comment: @AFinkelstein: Thanks! I've solved Part 1 of the problem, which was that it is cross-domain, so I had to add `crossDomain: true`, but now I'm getting `Access is denied.` as an error :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HOLY GUACAMOLE! This was some bug! Here's how I fixed it:

1. Added `jQuery.support.cors = true;` to the beginning of my script
2. Added `crossDomain: true` and `dataType: 'jsonp'` to my `$.ajax` options
3. Converted my JSON code to JSONP format like:

   `$_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');'`

And **VOILA!** The hardest bug I've debugged today.

Comment: Thanks! This really was hard to debug, or even hard to find this question :P Anyways, I just added crossDomain: true and it worked

Comment: No prob :) someone had to do it.